# on my macbook pro the linux OS's gparted differs from what blkid says about type of partition

Tags: linux-mint, partition, osx, windows

I have a multi-boot MBP retina;

(from linux mint 17.3 and last col. from windows diskpart):

```
tool        sudo blkid       gksudo gparted       windows 10 diskpart   Win10_GUI
/dev/sda1   EFI - vfat          EFI - fat32       fat32                 fat32
/dev/sda2   BOOTCAMP - ntfs     BOOTCAMP - ntfs   ntfs                  ntfs
/dev/sda3   DATA - hfs+         DATA - hfs+       ntfs                  raw
/dev/sda4   OSX - hfs+          OSX - hfs+        raw                   raw
/dev/sda5   Recovery - hfs+     Recovery - hfs+                         hfs+
/dev/sda6   swap                swap                                    raw
/dev/sda7   mint - ext4         mint - ext4                             ext3
/dev/sda8   swap                swap                                    raw
```

I disabled journaling btw

My question was which tool do I trust (I forgot long time ago how I formatted them) to tell which partition is of what type?

This came about because my windows 10 used to be able to read *and write* to my DATA partition (as did my others) but ever since I tried a trial version of Paragon, windows always wants me to format DATA (which it calls now D:) instead of opening it like I used to. It also is the same with E:\, which used to be able to be read and written to - it is where linux lives.

I remember I formatted everything using Mac software via Bootcamp, so Mac (and via Bootcamp drivers) and Windows could work with them. I then installed Win10 & lastly Mint and so it seems that these changes weren't reflected by Mac or Win10 and so it could still access them. I'm guessing the bootcamp drivers were why I could access my shared partition (hfs+)

I just installed a trial version of MacDisk 10 and now the labels I used on the partitions when they were created are back - so it seems to me that Paragon wasn't that great... or it initially "killed" my bootcamp drivers?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Though I suppose I'll just drop $50 for macdrive...

But my real question is if there is an easy way to get my bootcamp drivers to again read/write to my shared partition DATA. DATA was originally partitioned in mac to be hfs+, but then changed to something else - I can't remember, nor figure out from these terminal commands. All I know is I could read/write to it via all three OSs.

Hope this was clear...

**update**
Regarding first comment...

```
sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: hybrid
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with hybrid MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 1954210120 sectors, 931.8 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 2C519D1A-0CD6-467E-9C31-5DE30C329303
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1954210086
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 786321 sectors (383.9 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          409640       392664631   187.0 GiB   0700  DOS_FAT_32_Untitled_2
   3       392926776       925995247   254.2 GiB   AF00  Untitled
   4       926257392      1413531247   232.4 GiB   AF00  OS X
   5      1413531248      1414800783   619.9 MiB   AB00  Recovery HD
   6      1414800784      1453864959   18.6 GiB    8200  Untitled
   7      1453864960      1874454803   200.6 GiB   0700  DOS_FAT_32_Untitled_3
   8      1874716536      1954209791   37.9 GiB    8200  Untitled
```

and
    sudo fdisk -lu /dev/sda

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 1000.6 GB, 1000555581440 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121643 cylinders, total 1954210120 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x338f2781

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1      409639      204819+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda2   *      409640   392664631   196127496    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       392926776   925995247   266534236   af  HFS / HFS+
/dev/sda4       926257392  1413531247   243636928   af  HFS / HFS+
```

**update 2**

```
sudo file -ks /dev/sda3

/dev/sda3: Macintosh HFS Extended version 4 data (mounted) (unclean) last mounted by: 'H+Lx', created: Mon Oct  9 08:51:41 2147, last modified: Sat Aug 10 08:51:51 2148, block size: 4096, number of blocks: 66633559, free blocks: 31888651
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have hybrid  GPT and ms-dos partitioning on that drive. What do `gdisk -l /dev/sda` and `fdisk -lu /dev/sda` say?

Comment: I guess so... I read a little about gdisk vs. gparted and I am thinking that the former is a better option. So I guess I should trust gdisk over all others?

Comment: Wjat does `file -ks /dev/sda3` say?

Comment: I added the above edit...

Comment: I don't see a difference between gparted and blkid...